# MacOS Can't install headonly on homebrew (brew tap homebrew/headonly)

Tags: terminal, homebrew

This is what the terminal says after I put in this command brew tap homebrew/headonly

haven't tried anything to solve it yet, any suggestions please?

```
==> Tapping homebrew/headonly Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-headonly'...
remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-headonly/' not found Error:
Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-headonly /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-headonly --depth=1`
exited with 128
```

.

Comment: Why do you want to tap homebrew/headonly for?

Answer (score 1):

It’s normal: `homebrew/headonly` has been deprecated a long time ago, the repository doesn’t exist anymore. It was hard to maintain and so it didn’t really make sense to keep having it since anyone can [create their own tap](https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap).